# Does delay function work in C with 64 bit compilers?

Tags: c, file, header, delay

Does delay() work in C? In how many ways we can add time delay?

So, I had to give some time delay for my C program and delay() function worked quite well initially when I  was using code::blocks (which had an old 32 bit MinGW compiler by default.) Now when I downloaded and set up MinGW 64 bit for it, delay function doesn't work. So, I just switched to atom as someone had recommended me to use it and I'm using TDM-GCC-64 compiler and again delay is not working.

Whenever I use delay it says, `Warning: Implicit function declaration` and also `Undefined reference to delay`. So, basically how do I had time delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delay()` is not a standard function. It does exist for some compilers, but the error message is pretty clear. You have not included the necessary header for the particular function, and it may be the case that it does not even exist.

A similar function that exists in most C implemenations is `sleep()` and you find it in `unistd.h`. If you need to sleep for fractions of a second, you can instead use `nanosleep()` which replaces the older `usleep()`.